# No error but the app keeps stopping in android studio Java

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to an app for login app for emplyees, I have made three activities MainActivity, Register and Login. I have only designed the register activity and an onclick listener in login, and if the user is not logged in, the user is directed to Login, and an onclick listener to Register.Java, There is no error but the app keeps crashing and whenever i am opening the app in the emulator, the app does not open and it shows the this app keeps stopping.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.employeedatabase;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;

    public void updateUI(FirebaseUser account){

        if(account != null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"U Signed In successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,this.getClass()));

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"U Didnt signed in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Login.class));
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(currentUser);
    }

}
```

Login.java

```
package com.example.employeedatabase;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView Nuser = findViewById(R.id.new_user);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Nuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And at last there is Register.java

```
package com.example.employeedatabase;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private static final String TAG = "Register";

    public void updateUI(FirebaseUser account){

        if(account != null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"U Signed In successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,this.getClass()));

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"U Didnt signed in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Login.class));
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        String email = findViewById(R.id.email).toString();
        String password = findViewById(R.id.password).toString();

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail : Success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail : Failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

I want that if the user is not logged in it should open login.java, and if user click this text 'New User?, Sign In!'
I want the user to go to the Register.java

My Activity_register.xml is as follows.-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Register">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="228dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.743"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.048" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="263dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.479"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.187" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="257dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.14" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Rdone"
        android:layout_width="143dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Register"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.24000001" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I want to do atleast the app run, if any error is there i can correct but...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: No, there is an error in this one link which you sent, but i am not getting even a single error.

Comment: If it is telling you the app is crashing, there will be an error in Logcat.  Whatever you are doing to retrieve the error from the logs isn't working.  How are you getting logs?

Comment: It is not saying that the app is crashing but i am saying that whenever i run the app it just not opens and a message is diplayed in the avd that the app keeps stopping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your login activity, You cannot put this `TextView Nuser = findViewById(R.id.new_user);`  initialization at top level. it should be in oncreate method like this:

```
package com.example.employeedatabase;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView Nuser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Nuser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.new_user);
        Nuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note: You should put your logcat error in your question to get to the issue quickly or to solve any other issue which exists.

Comment: There was not even a single logcat error, but the app keeps crashing.